# How to setup and run Selenium with PhpStorm?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpstorm

I'm new to PHP + PhpStorm + Selenium

But I have sound knowledge on Java + Selenium + TestNG.

Any body can advice to start automation with PHP + PhpStorm + Selenium?

Comment: Facebook have an [implementation of the selenium webdriver in PHP](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver). Since you have knowledge in Java selenium testing the rest should work more or less the same.

Comment: Better search on Google for such stuff -- more likely to find relevant article. Maybe this one, for example: http://kurapov.ee/eng/qa/system_testing_selenium_phpstorm/

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use Behat/Mink/Selenium with PhpStorm.

Behat is a freamwork for testing automation written in PHP and it integrates perfectly with Phpstorm (natively).

Forget about PHPunit and Facebook php Selenium bindings...

http://behat.org/en/latest/